# get windows services install location in c#

Tags: c#, windows, service

I am developing a windows service which can get the install location of all windows services on the system it is running. I tried to get the location from registry but the names there are not consistent with the ones C# object returns. Any guidelines?

Comment: You can do it with PowerShell, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11219758/get-windows-services-install-location-in-c-sharp/11219838#11219838

Comment: @Jeremy, I read about PoweverShell a long while back. If I am right, it is a higher layer than WMI. If not, it is similar in concept. One major difference is PoweverShell uses scripting language, not with WMI. One link for example is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee309379(v=vs.85).aspx .

Answer (score 2):

I would be inclined to use ServiceController to find each of the installed services, and then look up the path in the Registry.

```
foreach (ServiceController c in ServiceController.GetServices())
{
     Console.WriteLine(c.DisplayName + " " + c.ServiceName);
}
```

Actually, now that I google it I found [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26533/A-ServiceController-Class-that-Contains-the-Path-t) solution that does something very similar.

Comment: I have done this already. I only now need to get the path from registry using these service name. But the issue is that these service names are different from the ones used in the registry. How do i resolve that.

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is to find information of all Windows Services, don't develop a Windows service. Simply make a simple software that uses WMI (Windows Management Instrumentation). A link [WMI and Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394602%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) gives you an idea. The example is written in VB script but you can do something similar in .NET.

Comment: No actually there are other things that this service also does like network and hardware information.

Comment: WMI also allows networking and hardware info. Basically WMI is a big layer between .NET or scripts and the Windows OS. Another method is to use the powerful .NET System classes. But then, you will have to learn different interfaces for each type of info. The lesson here is you have to read up on MSDN.

Comment: @Uzair, Did you try at least the sample VB script?

Answer (score -3):

First of all your idea is wrong. It will lead to access problems in different OS. You have to install in Program files and register it as service.

**P.S. Most of the Windows services runs from System32 folder**

Comment: He is not asking [how to install his service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984379(v=vs.71).aspx) he is asking for best practice in finding each services location. The registry gives him different results to using C# code.

Comment: yes that is what i am doing. This is itself a windows service which is installed in program files. it just needs to return the service name and service location of ALL the services installed on that system

Comment: I'm not telling how to install. Im telling this approach is wrong. All the windows services running from System32 folder. Why do you need to check for registry. You can check the services info using ServiceController Class. all of you..Please read the answer again.

Comment: ServiceController Class does not have the location object.

Comment: I re-read your answer but it is not a solution, thats all I'm saying. 
If you put code from the ServiceController class that demonstrates this - (eg using a Winform or console app rather than using a Windows Service) it would be a good answer. As it stands its more of a comment.

Comment: @Rajesh, Your solution is clever, that is to look at the System32 folder. However, there is still a challenge to figure out which sub-folders represent a Windows Service. And there are so many sub-folders; it's a huge amount. From the view of a Windows Systems Programmer, looking at a certain directory is not reliable in context of future Windows system.